# Lucene and Solr

Tags: lucene

I am creating the Index using Lucene.
But using the SolrSearch engine to search.

My problem is

1. while I index I add each filed in my
   **code using the code 
   doc.add(fieldname, val, tokenized)**

   1. **But my code does not see the schema file
   2. Even copy fields I need to add manually**
   3. **Now I want to use the autosuggest feature of Solr**
   4. **I do not know how to enable this feature while creating the Index**
2. But when I use the simplePostTool to post the data through Solr all is fine.
3. I cannot do that because I have to
   get some text from different urls.

   So can someone please advise me how
   can I achieve this? A sample code
   will be very helpful. In any case If
   I can have some code that can see
   the schema file and use the
   fieldTypes it would be great.

Thanks everyone.

--pramila

Answer (score 0):

See EmbeddedSolrServer at:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

It's a pure Java API to Solr, which will allow you to index your documents using the schema.xml you have defined.

Comment: Now I would like to use something that is mentioned here

Comment: http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2010/05/client-integration-with-solr-by-using.html

Comment: ContentStreamUpdateRequest , but I get errors when I do the server.request(req)